# How to add search bar between navbar headings on wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

I am using wordpress to create a website and wanted to put a nav bar in between my headings. For example if my navbar is:

Home About Products Information

I want it to be

Home About [SEARCH BAR] Products Information

I've heard about Ivory search but I think you can only put the bar either on the left or right side of the whole navbar so it's not going to work for me.